# Use MediaRecorder for live streaming / broadcasting into continuous 5-second segmented files among Android phones

Tags: android, mediarecorder, broadcasting

I am using MediaRecorder for live broadcasting among Android phones, but I don't want to use socket-based method. I want to record into 5-second segmented files, e.g.:

LIVE000.mp4  for the first 5 seconds

LIVE001.mp4   for the next 5 seconds

...

And then remote users can just continuously download the segments and display.

Now based on my tests, I can close and reopen the MediaRecorder every 5 second to save to continuous files, but the camera will also close and reopen with delay and sound, which is so bad.

So can I have any other method for my purpose? Should I use the low-layer APIs?

Thank you very much for your help! : )

Best 
Xiaofei

Comment: what is the problem with socket based method?

Comment: Hi, since we are testing another transmission design without IP, we don't use socket... : )